# qt label doesn't center text correctly

Tags: qt, qlabel

I have a QT application with a simple QLabel. When I tries to align text, it seems to works correctly,

```
m_c_label.setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft |Qt::AlignVCenter);
```

but if you look with attention, text is not vertically centered correclty, is displaced a few pixels to the bottom. I have tried with different layout configurations and always is the same problem.

It's a Qt 4.6 embedded application with qpf2 fonts. I have tried to change this font and with another font the text is desplaced to font so it seems to be a strange behaviour with the font. Any idea?

Comment: Please attach a screenshot to show what the problem is. Maybe your font is weirdly aligned to the bottomline of the text ?

Comment: It's a embedded system and i can't take a snapshot in an easy way. May be this could be the problem, but how I can see that in the font?

Comment: My guess is that the vertical alignment is based on the ascent and descent properties of the associated [`QFontMetrics`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html) rather than the \`tight' bounding rectangle of the actual text displayed.  Otherwise changing the text repeatedly would cause the apparent baseline of the text to jitter vertically.

Comment: I've been testing different solutions, like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404596/qpainter-with-qtaligncenter-does-not-center-text-correctly) but I always get the same result. My problem is text thasn't fit in the rect area if it is centered so I want to aling text almost centered, but 1 pixel up. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe the text is correctly centered in the label but the label isn't correctly centered in its layout?

Comment: `m_c_label.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter)` these works for me, but in case it doesn't for you, please i suggest you consider posting a minimal reproducible code because there may be some other widget or layout interferring

Comment: @XabiE please can you post a screenshot or a minimal reproducible code